# Extracting user uploaded archives without exposing to ZipBombs?

Tags: php, upload, archive

My question is simple: how do I make sure (or prevent) a user from uploading an archive that upon extraction fills the entire disc space (a so-called ZipBomb)? I am using PHP.

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903623/uploading-extracting-archive-zip-rar-targz-tarbz-automatically-security

Comment: Yes, but there is no solution to the problem other than Java's `ZipInputStream`.

Comment: list it's content first and check unpacked sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before extracting your archive, use the PHP Zip library functions to ensure that, when extracted, the contents fall within a total size limit.

For example:

```
$zip = zip_open('uploaded.zip');
$file = zip_read($zip);
$totalsize = 0;

while ($file) {
    $totalsize += zip_entry_filesize($file);
    $file = zip_read($zip); // read next file
}

zip_close($zip);

if ($totalsize > SIZE_LIMIT) {
    // not allowed!
}
```

Comment: [The comment below the manual entry for `zip_entry_filesize` mentions ZipBombs as well](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-filesize.php#98949)